# Trouble integrating react_on_rails into existing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-on-rails

I've followed the shakacode docs to a T but am having trouble getting react_on_rails integrated into my existing app. When I run

```
$ foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

I'm getting this in the console

```
10:28:24 web.1    | started with pid 36003

10:28:24 client.1 | started with pid 36004

10:28:26 client.1 | ReactOnRails: Set generated_assets_dir to default: public/webpack/development
10:28:26 web.1    | => Booting Puma

10:28:26 web.1    | => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 

10:28:26 web.1    | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

10:28:26 web.1    | ReactOnRails: Set generated_assets_dir to default: public/webpack/development

10:28:27 client.1 | yarn check v1.1.0

10:28:27 web.1    | yarn check v1.1.0

10:28:27 client.1 | success Folder in sync.

10:28:27 client.1 | Done in 0.21s.

10:28:27 web.1    | success Folder in sync.

10:28:27 web.1    | Done in 0.21s.

10:28:28 client.1 | Unknown switches '-w'

10:28:28 client.1 | exited with code 15

10:28:28 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes

10:28:28 web.1    | Exiting

10:28:28 web.1    | terminated by SIG
```

I'm still pretty new so I'm having trouble deciphering exactly what is wrong - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Procfile.dev, what do you use for client? Is it something like `bin/webpack`?

Comment: client: sh -c 'rm -rf public/packs/* || true && bundle exec rake react_on_rails:locale && bin/webpack -w'

Comment: In Procfile.dev I changed bin/webpack to webpack and it seems to work - still not sure why it works or if this is a legitimate fix

Comment: This issue on GitHub may provide some additional info: https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/956. It sounds like the error is caused by a conflict with the binstubs. There are a few different ways people have solved the issue. The way you fixed it is one of the solutions shared there.